# Getting error while creating schema in mysql using slick

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, akka-http

Error:

```
 value <> is not a member of (slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[String])    
 def * : ProvenShape[Employee] = (id, name, dept) <> (Employee.tupled, Employee.unapply)
```

My build.sbt look like this:

```
name := "AkkaHttpDemo"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
lazy val root = project in file(".")
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.6.8"  ,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.6.8",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.2.0",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.2",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.3.2",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.6" % Test,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.21"
)
```

Table schema look like this:

```
package services
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile._
import slick.ast.ScalaBaseType.stringType
import slick.lifted._
import slick.util._
trait EmployeeStore {
  class EmployeeStoreImpl(tag: Tag)  extends Table[Employee](tag, _schemaName = Some("MYSCHEMA"),"EMPL") {
    def id= column[String]("empid")
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def dept = column[String]("dept")

    def * : ProvenShape[Employee] = (id, name, dept) <> (Employee.tupled, Employee.unapply)
  }
  val dict = TableQuery[EmployeeStoreImpl]
}
```

Note*:  when I tried given below code also get the error

```
dict.schema.create
```

> Cannot resolve symbol schema

Comment: I would strongly recommend generating the Scala code from the schema, and not the other way around. https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.0/code-generation.html . The reason is that at some point you're going to have to write DB migrations for e. g. Flyway, and it's not possible to generate these using slick. On the other hand, running all the migrations on a test database and then generating the slick code from the resulting schema is trivial. Trust me, I've been there, and I wish somebody had told me back in the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the Slick API:

```
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._
```

You can also replace `<>` with the more convenient:

```scala
def *  = (id, name, dept).mapTo[Employee]
```

You likely don't need the `slick.ast`, `slick.lifted`, or `slick.util` imports, but I appreciate you including the full list of imports in your example.

Comment: I tried , but can you help me wth this error I am getting after using the mapTo

Comment: Type mismatch;
 found   : Employee.type
 required: scala.reflect.ClassTag[?]
   def *  = (id, name).mapTo(Employee)

Comment: Hi @varsha - note that `mapTo` takes a type parameter. That's in square brackets: `mapTo[Employee]` not `mapTo(Employee)`. But that's just a nicer way to write what you had with `<>`.